# Finding all Minimal Cut Sets for Site Percolation?

Tags: bugs, programming, graphs-and-networks, algorithm

**Bug introduced in 9.0 and persisting through 11.3.0**

`FindVertexCut` and `FindMinimumCut` are new in 9.0.

---

I want to disconnect the left side from the right side. The minimal cut set $C$ is a set of vertices by which the lattice $\mathbb L-C$ becomes disconnected. Consider the example below $\mathbb L=\mathbb L^2$ where an example minimal cut is $\{63,62\}$ for the below example: neither the set $\{62\}$ nor $\{62\}$ are minimal

```
SeedRandom[10801];
dimension = 10;
coDimension = 10;
percProbability = 0.489;
deleteMe = 
  Pick[Table[i, {i, dimension*coDimension}], 
   Table[RandomReal[] > percProbability, {i, 
     dimension*coDimension}]];
G = GridGraph[{dimension, coDimension}, VertexLabels -> "Name", 
   ImagePadding -> 30];
G = SetProperty[G, VertexCoordinates -> GraphEmbedding[G]];
H = VertexDelete[G, deleteMe]
(*ConnectedComponents[H]*)
FindVertexCut[H, 2, 97]
FindVertexCut[H]
FindMinimumCut[H]
```

[image]

where neither the FindVertexCut[] or FindMinimumCut[] do not work correctly: they suggest to remove isolated vertices and a compontent or not running, without anything to do with minimal vertex cuts. Because Mathematica's command on cuts not working so

**How can I find all minimal cut sets for a site percolation?**

Comment: Have you tried anything with [`FindMinimumCut[]`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FindMinimumCut.html)?

Comment: @blochwave I added a small example where you can see both the FindMinimumCut and FindVertexCut do not work on the grid graph so I would not use the functions.